How to amend a claim containing "preferably" to comply with clarity issues
I have noticed that examiners in the US and Canada usually complain about stating preferred values of a broader range in a claim. What would be the best way to amend such claim to comply with clarity?

There is nothing wrong with using the word “preferably” in relation to numerical values in the specification.
However a claim needs to define a boundary between what it covers and what it does not cover so there is no place for that word in any claim. Does a product infringe that doesn’t meet the “preferred” values?
You can use “about” and “an effective amount”.
You can have an independent claim with the broader values and a depended claim with narrower values. Each clear but one a subset of the other.
